# how can i limit showing comments in disqus comment box

Tags: javascript, web, disqus

I put a disqus comment box in my website, but that shows all comments at once. I want to configure the limit of showing comments. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this page: [disqus, the missing manual](http://blog.slashpoundbang.com/post/2592867566/disqus-the-missing-manual)

> `disqus_per_page` Number of comments per page. 0 for no limit. Default:
>   25.

Answer (score 1):

With Disqus 2012, there's no supported way to limit the number of comments shown on a page. By default the pagination begins after 50 comments, however.