# how to limit the comments showing in disqus comment box by 3

Tags: disqus

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102939/how-can-i-limit-showing-comments-in-disqus-comment-box) and checked [this one](http://blog.slashpoundbang.com/post/2592867566/disqus-the-missing-manual).

but I have no idea how to use `disqus_per_page`, and I am not sure if this is the right function to use. I am trying to limit the displayed comments on my disqus comment box by 3

I have tried adding `var disqus_per_page = 3;` but it does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
    var disqus_shortname = 'test'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
    var disqus_per_page = 3;

    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script');
        dsq.type = 'text/javascript';
        dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the suggestions in that post don't apply to the current version of Disqus, which doesn't have a way to limit the number of comments per page.

If you do need to show a more limited set of comments, the best practice right now is to use the API to show those few comments (you can choose between the newest comments, or the most voted, etc.), then provide a link to a page with the full Disqus embed.

We have a tutorial about showing comment counts that can be pretty easily adapted to showing comments as well: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1131783